# Does the concept of ahimsa make knowing and/or influencing thoughts, emotions and feelings of others paapam?

Tags: ahimsa

Does the concept of ahimsa make knowing and influencing thoughts, emotions and feelings of others as paapam?

When I say knowing and influencing thoughts, emotions and feelings of others, I mean knowing and influencing through technologies.

I do not mean something done by Yogic powers.

What punishments are recommended for knowing and influencing thoughts, feelings and emotions of others through technology? And what Karma will they suffer?

Comment: I think in all of ur Qs u are looking to know about the same thing .. I think that's bothering u seriously?

Comment: @Rickross Yes, you are saying it as if it wasn't obvious.

Comment: But probably using technologies to influence other's thoughts won't be discussed in scriptures .. so no way of answering the Q

Comment: lol, if it is too obvious then that's not good for u .. since u are a new user I was trying to be friendly with u ..

Comment: @Rickross My reply to you only included "Yes" but the character restrictions asked me to increase the length of my answers so I wrote "if it wasn't obvious".

Comment: Ok no problem .. You might be right but I can not think how to answer the Q

Comment: But ahimsa as a concept might include such things as violence, right? One doesn't have to be an erudite scholar to know that what causes pain and is therefore himsa

Comment: @Rickross Why did you use "u" to refer to me instead of "you"? Even though there were no character restrictions.

Comment: Because I am lazy ..

Comment: @Rickross I don't think you are lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You might be referring to some techniques like NLP, Mind Control for Influencing other people. 
Influencing can't be bad unless you do it for your evil intensions. 
Everybody has been influenced negatively or positively. 
If you influence someone for better it can't be bad.

My answer is practical and not based according to Scriptures... so please don't take it as an affirmation.

Comment: No I'm not referring to NLP  but use of technologies mentioned in my questions. I haven't used such technologies but I'm asking about others who use such technologies to abuse and deceive people.

Comment: Karma is neither man nor woman. It is believed to be universal force, if Karma is real why haven't people suffered for the things they've done.

Comment: @NeedAnswers Haven't you suffered from karma? I have I the past... It has a very subtle way of appearance... Its just that everything we do has a good effect or a bad one. Some effects are not felt in this life so they a carried  on to other life. Hence, we forget out actions...  Whatever you are experiencing good or bad. And whatever action u take now will determine your karma. So if one wants to make his luck good. Just do good karma.

Comment: Karma is similar to Newton's Third Law!

Comment: How should I know if what I suffered is a result of karma? What if it is result of some evil doings of people? We cannot accept anything without proof. If the misfortune which we might think is a result of karma, could be a result of some evil people.

Comment: So is the ultimate point you are making is that, if someone is torturing me through influencing my thoughts, feelings and emotions, do you expect me to accept it as a result of my karma?

Comment: If someone is doing bad to us... Always fight for good. If your karma has to do something with it... It will eventually happen. But dharma must win.

Comment: What do you mean by "if your karma has to do something with it ... it will eventually happen"? Is what my abusers doing dharma?